# Getting TypeScript error and Cannot find type definition file for '@types/testing-library__cypress'. TS2688

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm

Build is throwing error in one of the instance,Now in my local with the same set up, The image is getting created successfully without any error.

**Error Message :**

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

**TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined):
Cannot find type definition file for '@types/testing-library__cypress'.  TS2688**


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ocl-client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ocl-client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-02T14_21_43_413Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Resolved the same issue in local by following below steps.**

> 1. To get rid of TS2688 Error, Changed the version for "@testing-library/cypress" in both the file package.json & package-lock.json
>      (Ref. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json)
> 2. Run the command npm install
> 3. docker build -t ImageName .
>      It worked as expected...

**Observation:**
I may be misleading here,but in my AWS instance I don't see npm command under root user.

Q. Is npm is specific to user ?

```
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-23-192 ~]$ npm root
    /home/ec2-user/node_modules
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-23-192 ~]$ sudo su
    [root@ip-172-31-23-192 ec2-user]# npm root
    bash: npm: command not found
```

I am completely new to node.js , is there anything am I missing here ?, Any lead will be very helpful.

Comment: Do you have `@types/testing-library__cypress` installed in dev-dependencies?

Comment: yes it is.. there I have changed the version too.